# how to convert float to string excluding NaN in pandas within one line code?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert a column of float value to string, following is my current way:

```
userdf['phone_num'] = userdf['phone_num'].apply(lambda x: "{:.0f}".format(x) if x is not None else x)
```

However, it also converts the NaN to string "nan" which is bad when I check the missing value in this column, any better idea?

Thanks!

Comment: `userdf['phone_num'].astype('str')`

Comment: or: `df.phone_num.where(pd.notnull, df.phone_num.astype(str))` if you want to keep `NaN` type...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should compare Nan values instead of comparing None

```
userdf['phone_num'] = userdf['phone_num'].apply(lambda x: "{:.0f}".
                                          format(x) if not pd.isnull(x) else x)
```

Comment: Both of your answer and @AkshayNevrekar are good, but it leaves the missing value in 'phone_num' column with type 'float' while others are string.

Comment: so if you want a default value then you can put that in the if condition in the answer above. So maybe you can put something like NA if value is NaN

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Thanks!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's good, but the issue is just as I answered above, thanks anyway!